# What is the right way to include plugins files in plugin system

Tags: php, plugins, include

I've created a plugins system, and I've created everything in that system except, how can I inclusion plugins files to execute it.

I'm tried to create a method, Which is doing include plugins files to execute it.

**-- Firstly -- :**
The method that get all plugins files, and that begin with `index` word which indicates the main file of plugin (i.g. index-pluginName.php), and add the path and file name to an array.

```
public function getPluginFiles($plugin_folder) {
  $dir = opendir($plugin_folder);
  while ($files = readdir($dir)) {
     if ($files == '.' || $files == '..')
        continue;

     if (is_dir($plugin_folder.'/'.$files))
        $this->getPluginFiles($plugin_folder.'/'.$files);


     if (preg_match('/^[index]+/i', $files)) {
        $this->plugins_path[$plugin_folder.'/'.$files] = $files;
     }
  }
  closedir($dir);       
}
```

**-- secondly -- :**
The method that include all the main file of plugins to execute, and this method get the path and name of plugin file from the array that created earlier .

```
public function includePlugFiles() {
   $this->getPluginFiles($this->plugin_folder);
   foreach ($this->plugins_path as $dir=>$file) {
     include_once (dirname($dir)."/".$file);
   }
}
```

Also see an example of code that exists in plugin file:

```
function test() {
    echo " This is first plugin <br/>";
}

$plugin->addHook('top', test); // parameters(top=position, test=callback)
```

Now, when I create an instance of the object to be this form .

```
$plugin = new plugin;
$plugin->includePlugFiles();
```

But after all this, shows error message

`Fatal error: Call to a member function addHook() on a non-object in .... projects\plugins\index-test.php on line 7`

This is the code of line 7:

```
$plugin->addHook('top', test); // parameters(top=position, test=callback)
```

I know the problem occur because, the object will not be created.
and the problem is can't create the object in every main plugin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the cleanest solution, but instead of trying to reference the `$plugin` symbol (which is outside the scope of the plugin file), you could also do this:

```
$this->addHook('top', test);
```

Alternatively, you could explicitly create the reference inside the `includePlugFiles()` method:

```
public function includePlugFiles()
{
     $plugin = $this;

     $this->getPluginFiles($this->plugin_folder);
     foreach ($this->plugins_path as $dir=>$file) {
         include_once (dirname($dir)."/".$file);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution very good, It works correctly. but so far, I don't understand how it works. can you explain to me more how it now work correctly .

Comment: Also I have modified `$this->addHook('top', test);` to `$plugin->addHook('top', test);` and also works correctly. is there problem with this modifier?

Comment: @LionKing it would become more obvious why it didn't work when you add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script; inside the plugin code file there's no variable called `$plugin` because that's defined outside of `includePlugFiles()` method.